# plugin.yml Aliases Error: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create a custom Minecraft server plugin for my localhost server, but in the Console, it keeps showing that there's a problem with my aliases in `plugin.yml`. I've even tried just removing the aliases completely and leaving only the regular commands, but it doesn't seem to be updating.

I run Eclipse on my Mac and it doesn't let me run `.yml` files directly in Eclipse, so it opens Xcode every time and I don't know if that's part of the issue or not. I've made sure to always save my `plugin.yml` file and have everything in the right place.

It is not an issue of my server running incorrectly as I have a working plugin that I've downloaded from the Internet. I have attached screenshots that will hopefully help.

**Screenshot of plugin.yml:**

[image: Screenshot of plugin.yml]

**Screenshot of Console aliases error:**

[image: Screenshot of Console aliases error]

Comment: Can you post your `plugin.yml` file in text form, so we could accurately see what went wrong?  Also, I recommend to use a [YAML Parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to check if there is actually wrong in the formatting of your plugin.yml file.  Lastly, check to make sure that the server is running the latest version of your plugin, because you've mentioned that removing the aliases completely still doesn't do any update to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If the editor could not handle .yml files then it could cause this error because of random tabs or invalid syntax management. Also you said you don't see any update after editing. I would suggest check that you compiled the plugin after the modifications and the server has the latest jar file in the plugins folder.